# How do I center a packed chain in a ConstraintLayout that contains a View with width `0dp`?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, constraint-layout-chains

I want to center the headline of my page. The headline can look like `(1) Dokument1` or `(3) GreatDocument`. I want to have right and left margins of `60dp` and the name of the document has a variable length. When I use `wrap_content` for `@+id/title` the centering works well, however the margins don't work for long names of documents. When I use `0dp` the margins get respected but the centering doesn't work.

How do I get the packed chain in my ConstraintLayout to center while having a dynamic length and having margins.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/top_bar_xml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/open_brackets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="("
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"

        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/page_count"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/page_count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/open_brackets"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/close_brackets"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/close_brackets"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=") "
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/page_count"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
        android:text="DocumentTitle"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/close_brackets"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

*(I simplified the example by removing references to ViewModels for page count and title; the document has additional Views below that have a lower margin)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set width of `@id/title` to `wrap_content` and add

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

attribute to it so that the constraints of that `TextView` are respected when it gets too big to satisfy the margins.